# what is wrong with my logic? if any conditions are true, then

Tags: bash

I feel like my brain stopped working. Clearly, this logic is wrong but I can't figure it out. I suspect I just need to negate the whole thing, but not sure...why does the following not work:

```
#!/bin/bash
a=0
b=20
c=30
d="yes"
e="yes"

echo a,b,c,d,e = $a, $b, $c, $d, $e
if [[ $a -eq 1 || $b -gt $c || $d -eq "no" || $e -eq "no" ]];
then
echo a is 1, or b is greater than c, or d is no, or e is no
else
echo no conditions are true
fi
```

result:

```
a,b,c,d,e = 0, 20, 30, yes, yes
a is 1, or b is greater than c, or d is no, or e is no
```

Comment: what do you think is wrong and what do you want to achieve?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use `-eq` to compare strings - it only compares numbers. Use `=` instead.

Comment: wow, that was easy. In the midst of all my efforts to understand (( [[ and all, I forgot most basic ==